# Running System Shock: Enhanced Edition with Wine errors out

Tags: wine

I've been trying to get System Shock: Enhanced Edition (from gog.com) to run with Wine, however, it displays the title screen for a few seconds and then errors out:

```
[~/.wine/drive_c/GOG Games/System Shock - Enhanced Edition]% wine sshock.exe
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f974,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW (L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY1",0,0x33f974,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW (L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY1",0,0x33f4c8,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW (L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY1",1,0x33f974,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),1,0x33f974,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f974,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),1,0x33f974,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:xinput:XInputGetCapabilities (index 3, flags 0x1, capabilities 0x33fb8c) Stub!
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x70120, filter=0x109e96c,flags=0x00000000) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:win:RegisterTouchWindow (0x7011e 00000003): stub
fixme:wgl:X11DRV_wglChoosePixelFormatARB unused pfAttribFList
fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0x7011e, 0x13c030): stub
fixme:msctf:ThreadMgr_ActivateEx Unimplemented flags 0x4
fixme:msctf:ThreadMgrSource_AdviseSink (0x13a050) Unhandled Sink: {ea1ea136-19df-11d7-a6d2-00065b84435c}
fixme:imm:NotifyIME NI_CLOSECANDIDATE
fixme:msctf:ThreadMgrSource_AdviseSink (0x13a050) Unhandled Sink: {ea1ea136-19df-11d7-a6d2-00065b84435c}
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f444,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33efd4,0x00000000), stub!
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 ()
  Minor opcode of failed request:  4
  Value in failed request:  0x2c02082
  Serial number of failed request:  18960
  Current serial number in output stream:  18961
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Exit 1
```

This is on Arch Linux with wine 2.0-rc3. I also tried this some while ago with Wine 1.9.x or 1.8.x with the same results, so it doesn't seem specific to this recent Wine version.

According to several sources this should work with Wine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `sshock.ini` with any plain text editor and change:

```
SoftRenderer=Off
```

to:

```
SoftRenderer=On
```

This seems to have fixed the problem for me; thus far I've played the game for about an hour without problems.

I don't know why so many sources say it should work out-of-the-box. Perhaps it's related to my video card (intel HD) and/or window manager (PekWM).